# Is there any way to name Vertex Pipelines components in the UI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

The Vertex Pipelines UI uses component name with numeric suffix as the default name in the UI. Is this customizable?

Answer (score 0):

For a regular step, you can use `.set_display_name('foo')`. Reference: https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/master/source/dsl.html#kfp.dsl.PipelineTask.set_display_name

For `parallelFor`, you can do the following (KFP SDK V2.0+ only)

```
with dsl.ParallelFor([], name='bar') as yv:
```